# Reduce custom tick font size and change color

Tags: lightningchart

I am adding custom tick like below

```
 axisX3.addCustomTick()
    .setGridStrokeLength(0)
    .setTextFormatter(()=> ttstr[0]+":"+ttstr[1])
    .setValue(xVal);
```

[image]

1. How do I change font size / color
2. change border color  / style
3. remove the rectangle around the ticks and just show the pointer in top.

I tried

```
 .setTitleFont(f => f
        .setSize(24)
    )
```

But not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the visual style of the created tick with [`customTick.setMarker()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/customtick.html#setmarker) method. This method takes a mutator function as the first and only argument.

To change the font size:

```js
const tick = axisX.addCustomTick()
    .setMarker(marker => marker
        .setFont(font => font
            .setSize(40)
        )
    )
```

To style the border:

```js
const tick = axisX.addCustomTick()
    .setMarker(marker => marker
        .setBackground(background => background
            .setStrokeStyle((line) => line
                .setFillStyle(style => style
                    .setColor(ColorHEX('#f00'))
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Showing just the pointer is not possible.

See below for a snippet of styling the tick.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    emptyLine,
    ColorHEX,
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

const axisX = chart.getDefaultAxisX()

const tick = axisX.addCustomTick()
    .setMarker(marker => marker
        .setFont(font => font
            .setSize(40)
        )
        .setBackground(background => background
            .setStrokeStyle((line) => line
                .setFillStyle(style => style
                    .setColor(ColorHEX('#f00'))
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .setValue(4)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```